# Spring MVC - Invalid view being executed (violating specified request mapping)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have been trying to debug it for like hours and even tried to create the same project over and again. I don't know whether it's the issue due to IntelliJ IDEA or something else. I tried to google but couldn't find any solution. I am making a simple spring mvc demo application in intelliJ. A default structure was provided by intelliJ and a view "index.jsp" in web directory.

[image: project structure]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

**DebugController.java**

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Created by gaurav.ahirwar on 29/05/17.
 */

@Controller

public class DebugController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String debug() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I run the project and hit localhost:8080/ then index.jsp is executed but according to my configuration and mapping hello.jsp should be loaded. It may be possible that I am doing some silly mistake but I have tried as much as I can and now really frustrated. Please help me out. Thanks.

localhost:8080

[image: index.jsp loaded at root]

Answer (score 0):

Try this mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"", "/", "index.jsp"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I guess localhost:8080 equals `""` path, but not `/`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work. Still index.jsp is loaded! 


PS: I already tried localhost:8080 and localhost:8080/ it's just same.

Comment: It's strange. I use SpringBoot and for me it works... :-(

Comment: That is why I posted it here. I cannot figure out what's causing this. :/